# How Windows could prevent store apps from using system headers?

Tags: windows, windows-runtime

I am curious about this when I am getting to know more about programming WinRT app. Normally for regular Windows programs, developers can use system headers like WinINet.h or WinHttp.h, etc. However, it is not allowed to use them in an WinRT store app.

I was wondering what way they use to prevent developer from using those dlls, how do they check, and why they do this to developers?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Windows Store apps run inside of an `AppContainer`. All of the dlls and libraries that they are allowed to import/use are limited by the rights of the `AppContainer`. Generally, the apps have the rights of the user "ALL_APPLICATION_PACKAGES" I believe, so that means that they have the read/write capabilities of that user. They still are only able to access the system via the `AppContainer`, so any limitations imposed by the `AppContainer` still exist.

Now, there is a way around this. The developer can use the `FileOpenPicker` to allow the user to choose a file or folder (via the `FolderPicker`) that the program can use.

They do this to developers to make it so that the `AppContainer` is a very closed-off sandbox running in basically a virtual environment. In this way, simply for the fact that a program is running inside of the `AppContainer`, it can be said to protect the users data and prevent the installation of malware.

This does not necessarily prevent an app from social engineering or phishing. That is policed via the certification and compliance system.